# Почему не срабатывает конструктор копирования?

Tags: c++

```
class cl {
public:
    static int s;
    int s1;
    int n;
    cl(int n):n(n) { ++s; s1 = s; cout << "basic constructor " << s1 << "\n"; }
    cl(const cl& nn):n(nn.n) { ++s; s1 = s; cout << "const copy " << s1 << "\n"; }
    
    explicit operator int() { return n; }
};

int main(){
 cl a(cl(8));
}
```

Выводит базовый конструктор, как так получается, что преобразовывает в число?
и почему обычный конструктор не срабатывает при создании временного объекта?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/companies/vk/articles/666330/

Answer (score 2):

Return Value Optimization

При компиляции код

```
cl a(cl(cl(cl(8))));
```

просто будет оптимизирован до `cl a(8);`, так как эти временные значения не сохраняются

Конструктор копирования будет вызван при сохранении ссылок на оба объекта

```
int main(){
 cl a(cl(8));
 cl b = a; // copy
}
```

Comment: Только с уточнением, что это уже давно не "оптимизация", а требование стандарта, которое ключами отключения оптимизации не отключить...

Comment: таких тонкостей не знал, спасибо